# Django returns error on ModelChoiceField with values rendered in runtime

Tags: python, django, django-forms

First the idea: I have a manger, who manages different branches each of which has restaurants assigned to them. I want him to be able to make orders and choose restaurants available for his specific branch. I use a class with static values to remember which manager is making the order.

Second: the code.
forms.py:

```
class NewOrderFormManager(Form):
    restaurant = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)
    # other fields here

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewOrderFormManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        branches = StaticData.get_branches_assigned_to_manager()
        self.fields['restaurant'].queryset = Restaurant.objects.filter(branch__in=branches)
```

views.py:

```
class NewOrderFromManagerFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'admin_custom/new_order_from_manager_form.html'
    form_class = NewOrderFormManager

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        StaticData.find_branches_corresponding_to_manager(request.user)
        return super(NewOrderFromManagerFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        StaticData.find_branches_corresponding_to_manager(request.user)
        return super(NewOrderFromManagerFormView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # some code to be executed
```

storage class:

```
class StaticData:
    branches = None

    @classmethod
    def find_branches_corresponding_to_manager(cls, user):
        cls.branches = None
        if roles.has_role(user, roles.ROLE_ADMIN):
            cls.branches = Branch.objects.all()
        elif roles.has_role(user, roles.ROLE_COURIER_MANAGER):
            cls.branches = user.couriermanager.branches.all()

    @classmethod
    def get_branches_assigned_to_manager(cls):
        return cls.branches
```

Third: the problem.
There seams to be some trouble with posting a request for some specific restaurant. When I access `clean()` method I can find an error saying that the choice I've made is not valid and I should choose another. I am using superadmin'`account for this purpose and I've checked that I get correct branches when I call`StaticData`. The`restaurant`simply doesn't appear in`cleaned_data`. I've tried both digging into django's documentation and sourcecode but to na avail as for now.

UPDATE:
I've inspected the server log output and I see that on clicking "submit" button it uses GET:

```
"GET /custom_admin/new_order_from_manager/restaurant=5&price=0.04&phone_number=123123123&street=Gwarna&house_number=1&flat_number=&comment= HTTP/1.1" 200 13887
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the lack of `csfr token` was a problem, so I've added it to my form:

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
```